# Is there a size limit on returnObject from Code.gs?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a size limit on a functions `returnObject` from Code.gs?

I've implemented several functions using the same logic, however when I do the following where the Sheet's named range has `6000` rows (with 21 columns):

**custom_js_file.js**

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successHandlerMyGreatFunction).withFailureHandler(failureHandlerMyGreatFunction).myGreatFunction();
```

**Code.gs**

```
function myGreatFunction() {

var active_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("AAAA");

var active_sheet = active_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("BBBB");

var my_entries = active_sheet.getRange("my_entries_range").getValues();

var return_object = {};

return_object['my_entries'] = my_entries; 

return return_object;

}
```

I get:

> ScriptError: The script completed but the returned value is not a
>   supported return type.

I've tried variations of the above:

- using `getDataRange()`
- just returning `my_entries` without adding it as a key value in the variable `return_object`.

But I get the same message.

The only anomalies I can think of is that the sheet has frozen columns and has 6000 rows - will either of those negatively effect the `returnObject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because:

> apparently Date-types are not a legal parameter-type or return-type
>   (this also applies to variables in arrays, objects, ...)

from:  [Google Apps Script return object in Code.gs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27643515/1063287)

So amended code is:

```
function myGreatFunction() {

var active_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("AAAA");

var active_sheet = active_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("BBBB");

var my_entries = active_sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

var return_object = {};

return_object['my_entries'] = my_entries; 

return return_object;

}
```

It utilises [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValues()) rather than [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()).

I don't know if this raises any other data accuracy issues etc.